# Managing navigation and page states in MVC

Tags: design-patterns, model-view-controller, navigation

There are few points I would like to get a crisper idea about when it comes to best practices for managing navigation and page states when using Model-View-Controller architecture:

**View/page navigation:**

There are a number of navigation types that we need to track:

- normal navigation: just moving around.
- modal navigation: there are modal views where we would like to go back to the calling page.
- inter-section navigation: when views are organized into section, we need to keep track of state, so that if the user navigates away from a section and back, we can take them to their last view within the section.
- resuming after interruption: we need to be able to decide the last page when resuming from interruption.

All these navigation paths are managed as I understand it, by sending events to some event handler in the controller, and the event handler will:

- keep track of the navigation states.
- interact with the model
- issue calls to appropriate views within the View.

**View/page states:**

The most common example is pages/views with states that the user sets before launching an operation, if the page is navigated away from, or interrupted otherwise, we need to recreate the last page state using stored states.

On this point, I'm assuming page states belong in the View, but not sure about the proper design for them, for example, do we use a page object for each view/page, or do we use a central state object and so on.

**Edit: on the context of the question:**

I have an application that would be materialized into two forms: a web application and a mobile app. The web application is done in Python Flask (or maybe later with something more advanced like Django), and the app in Java/Android. A minimal web application is developed first, so it serves as a model for the mobile app too.

With this scenario, there are two main concerns:

- Full isolation of the Model, so that converting it would be just a matter of direct translation.
- Organizing View and Control with best practices applied in order to minimize refactoring when converting, and to keep both environments as parallel as possible to minimize maintenance overheads.

With the above in mind, I needed a clearer picture on where the specific details I listed would fit.

Comment: Is this in the context of desktop or web application? Also, what exactly is your question?

Comment: Thanks - please see the edit on context.

Comment: And my question is whether my understanding of where things belong is correct.I came across a few descriptions of the architectural pattern that are somewhat generic, but I wanted to know where things belong exactly at the level of the specific details I mentioned. And how they are organized within the architecture (the point in last paragraph).